# Problem switching from DataMapper to Active Record in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

I have removed my DataMapper specific models and gems in my Rakefile and removed all databases. I also updated my database.yml file. Now, when I attempt to generate a model with

```
rails g model Car year:integer make:string model:string
```

I get:

```
No value provided for required options '--orm'
```

Is there someplace that I am missing the specification of Active Record? I've been unable to find any documentation for switching an application's ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in `config/application.rb`, you may have a line that looks like this:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.orm :datamapper
end
```

Change that `:datamapper` symbol to `:active_record` or remove that line completely to switch back to ActiveRecord.

If it's not there, you may have a file in `config/initializers` which does this setup for you.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any config for generators or datamapper in either place, so I added the config.generators block you mentioned with :active_record and tried to generate a model again, which gave me: error  active_record [not found]

Comment: Add `activerecord` gem to your Gemfile and run `bundle install` after doing what Ryan suggested

Comment: @jdscosta91 I think it's likely that the OP has fixed their problem by now ;)